# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library “libXXXXX.so.0” not found

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

I have created `libXXXXX.so` from the third-party sources in my android cross-compiling environment. The build was successful, but the execution was the following error.

Error log(logcat)

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libXXXXX.so.0" not found
```

I think that **so.0** is something wrong, but I don't know how to handle it in Android Studio.

The result of `readelf`:

```
$readelf -d libXXXXX.so | grep SONAME<br>
0x000000000000000e (SONAME) Library soname: [libXXXXX.so.0]
```

`CMakeLists.txt` is like this:

```
add_library( libXXXXX SHARED IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( libXXXXX PROPERTIES
IMPORTED_LOCATION ${LIB_ROOT}/cpp/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libXXXXX.so )

add_library(hello-jni SHARED src/main/cpp/hello-jni.cpp )

target_link_libraries( hello-jni libXXXXX ${log-lib} )
```

Java source code:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}
```

- In the case of `libXXXXX.a` (STATIC LIBRARY) was successfully executed.
- `libXXXXX.so.0` is placed in the same folder as `libXXXXX.so`.

How about attaching SONAME related options to `CMakeLists.txt`? I try it, but I don't understand well.

Could anyone suggest any solutions?

**Status change.**

I add `libXXXXX.so` as loadLibrary in Java code.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("XXXXX");
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}
```

Error log is as follow:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "acos" referenced by "...libXXXXX.so"...
```

No function acos in Android? Any solutions?

**Added libm, but it remains the same error**

CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries( hello-jni libXXXXX m ${log-lib} )
```

Java source code:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("m");
    System.loadLibrary("XXXXX");
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}
```

Comment: how are you calling the library in your android project ? please provide the steps you followed to add the library to the project and to call it.

Comment: I added some information.

Comment: I don't recommend using native libraries of many functions in cross-compiling. It will be  deeper into a hole. We should find another way to implement.